# moving average difference between numpy and mathdotnet.com

Tags: numpy, moving-average, math.net

First, a picture:

[image]

Column A is my source data, 50 points.
Column C and D are the SMA calculated with numpy and mathdotnet.com, respectively, with a window of 15.

Column F is the delta.

As we can see, about halfway, the data becomes identical, but the first half is not. I do not understand why, and, more importantly, do not know what to trust.

So I got from SO an optimized version of the SMA and ran the data through it.
The code is here:

```
    private static NDArray SMA(this NDArray Data, int Period)
    {
        var Length = Data.len;

        // calculate the moving average
        var Buffer = new double[Period];
        var Output = new double[Length];

        var CurrentIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            Buffer[CurrentIndex] = Data.GetDouble(i) / Period;
            var MA = 0.0;
            for (var j = 0; j < Period; j++)
            {
                MA += Buffer[j];
            }

            Output[i] = MA;
            CurrentIndex = (CurrentIndex + 1) % Period;
        }

        var R = new ArraySegment<double>(Output, Period - 1, Length - Period + 1);
        return new NDArray(R.ToArray());
    }
```

It is using NumSharp, the .net port of numpy, to hold the source array.

While it is all different code, the C# code and python numpy output the same results (differences happen after the 12th decimal point, so we can consider them identical).

This points out to mathdotnet.com being different; so I guess I can trust the numpy / C# versions more.

Are there different variations of the SMA that could cause this? or something obvious I don't see?

I have put all the data here: https://pastebin.com/WgYJUUJF

---

Edit:

Here is the numpy code:

```
import numpy as np

def calcSma(data, smaPeriod):
    j = next(i for i, x in enumerate(data) if x is not None)
    our_range = range(len(data))[j + smaPeriod - 1:]
    empty_list = [None] * (j + smaPeriod - 1)
    sub_result = [np.mean(data[i - smaPeriod + 1: i + 1]) for i in our_range]

    return np.array(empty_list + sub_result)

def calcSma2(data_set, periods=3):
    weights = np.ones(periods) / periods
    return np.convolve(data_set, weights, mode='valid')

a = np.array([1.1282553063375, 1.13157696082132, 1.13275406120136, 1.1332879715733, 1.12761933580452, 1.12621836040801, 1.12282485875706, 1.12265572041877, 1.13094386506532, 1.12320520490577, 1.12427293064877, 1.1328332027022, 1.13099445663901, 1.12843355605048, 1.13002750724853, 1.12843355605048, 1.13099445663901, 1.12709476494142, 1.12684879712348, 1.12672349888807, 1.12600933402474, 1.13112070248549, 1.12985951088976, 1.12822416032659, 1.12471789559362, 1.12651004224413, 1.12442669033881, 1.12334638977164, 1.12714333124378, 1.1312233808195, 1.12713229372575, 1.128255040952, 1.12585669781931, 1.12763457442902, 1.12470631424376, 1.12223443223443, 1.12506842815956, 1.12691187181355, 1.12385654130971, 1.13026344596074, 1.12237927400894, 1.1245915922457, 1.13088395780284, 1.13211944646759, 1.12590649028825, 1.12829127560895, 1.11876736364966, 1.12222667492441, 1.12169543369019, 1.12199031071285])


b = calcSma(a, 15)
c = calcSma2(a, 15)

print b

print "----------------------------------"

print c
```

and here is the mathdotnet one:

```
var data = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(new[] { 1.1282553063375, 1.13157696082132, 1.13275406120136, 1.1332879715733, 1.12761933580452, 1.12621836040801, 1.12282485875706, 1.12265572041877, 1.13094386506532, 1.12320520490577, 1.12427293064877, 1.1328332027022, 1.13099445663901, 1.12843355605048, 1.13002750724853, 1.12843355605048, 1.13099445663901, 1.12709476494142, 1.12684879712348, 1.12672349888807, 1.12600933402474, 1.13112070248549, 1.12985951088976, 1.12822416032659, 1.12471789559362, 1.12651004224413, 1.12442669033881, 1.12334638977164, 1.12714333124378, 1.1312233808195, 1.12713229372575, 1.128255040952, 1.12585669781931, 1.12763457442902, 1.12470631424376, 1.12223443223443, 1.12506842815956, 1.12691187181355, 1.12385654130971, 1.13026344596074, 1.12237927400894, 1.1245915922457, 1.13088395780284, 1.13211944646759, 1.12590649028825, 1.12829127560895, 1.11876736364966, 1.12222667492441, 1.12169543369019, 1.12199031071285 });
var sma = Vector<double>.Build.Dense(data.MovingAverage(15).Skip(14).ToArray());
var s = sma.Aggregate(string.Empty, (Current, v) => Current + $"{v}, ");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: I would guess it's because they are handling the edges differently. It's trivial for you to hand calculate the moving average yourself. If you have a 15 point MA, then your result must b 14 elements shorter than the original. The way around this is to pad the edges. You could do it with 0, with reflection, by repeating element 1. I assume that numpy and Math.NET have different defaults. I also assume you can probably change their behaviour with an argument.

Comment: mathdotnet and the c# code trim the first 14 elements; numpy fills them with 'none'; they are out of the excel graph; what you see is the last 36 elements. so, you think that these elements do impact the rest of the calculation? probably for the same as the window length - 1, then?

Comment: If you've left off the first 14 elements in that excel sheet, then just calculate the MA yourself in Excel? It's trivial. And then you'll see which one is right. But I can't see why they would be different if it's not by the edges

Comment: yes, I think I need to do the manual calculation in excel to see what's up. The first 14 elements is probably where it's at but with different results, it's hard to know what to trust!

Comment: Also post your mathdotnet  and numpy code?

Comment: I just added both code versions

Comment: Just had a look at the example, but failed to reproduce the difference. The posted code sample using Math.NET Numerics returns exactly the same values as you've posted as returned by numpy. I've verified with v4.9.1. Do you remember which version you were using?

Comment: I know that the project was a .net core project, but as far as the lib, etc I don't recall because it was like 9 months ago.